# Will this wrong command harm my Ubuntu OS after reboot?

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install archlinux on a Pogoplug.... But I got an error saying permission was denied because I was not root... So I know to associate "sudo" with root, but I didn't think until afterwards that sudo might only be used as the root command for the ubuntu OS... I checked the directory folder on the Ubuntu drive, and sure enough I had written the script to it...

This is the command I entered

```
/tmp$ sudo ./install_uboot_mtd0.sh
```

This is what it spit out..........

```
    !!!!!!  DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER DANGER  !!!!!!

If you lose power to your device while running this script,
it could be left in an unusable state.

This script will replace the bootloader on /dev/mtd0.

This installer will only work on the following devices:
 Seagate Dockstar
 Seagate GoFlex Net
 Seagate GoFlex Home
 Pogoplug v1
 Pogoplug Pink (v2)
Do not run this installer on any other device.

By typing ok, you agree to assume all liabilities and risks 
associated with running this installer.

If you agree, type 'ok' and press ENTER to continue: ok
# checking for /usr/sbin/nandwrite...

# Installing /usr/sbin/nandwrite...
--2013-12-30 09:12:24--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/nandwrite.md5
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/nandwrite.md5'

    [ <=>                                   ] 32          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:24 (3.18 MB/s) - `/usr/sbin/nandwrite.md5' saved [32]

--2013-12-30 09:12:24--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/nandwrite
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11500 (11K) []
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/nandwrite'

100%[======================================>] 11,500      --.-K/s   in 0.03s   

2013-12-30 09:12:25 (359 KB/s) - `/usr/sbin/nandwrite' saved [11500/11500]

# Successfully installed /usr/sbin/nandwrite.
# checking for /usr/sbin/nanddump...

# Installing /usr/sbin/nanddump...
--2013-12-30 09:12:25--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/nanddump.md5
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/nanddump.md5'

    [ <=>                                   ] 32          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:26 (2.60 MB/s) - `/usr/sbin/nanddump.md5' saved [32]

--2013-12-30 09:12:26--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/nanddump
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 21286 (21K) []
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/nanddump'

100%[======================================>] 21,286      --.-K/s   in 0.07s   

2013-12-30 09:12:26 (303 KB/s) - `/usr/sbin/nanddump' saved [21286/21286]

# Successfully installed /usr/sbin/nanddump.
# checking for /usr/sbin/flash_erase...

# Installing /usr/sbin/flash_erase...
--2013-12-30 09:12:26--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/flash_erase.md5
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/flash_erase.md5'

    [ <=>                                   ] 32          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:27 (3.33 MB/s) - `/usr/sbin/flash_erase.md5' saved [32]

--2013-12-30 09:12:27--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/flash_erase
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12819 (13K) []
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/flash_erase'

100%[======================================>] 12,819      --.-K/s   in 0.06s   

2013-12-30 09:12:27 (210 KB/s) - `/usr/sbin/flash_erase' saved [12819/12819]

# Successfully installed /usr/sbin/flash_erase.
# checking for /usr/sbin/fw_printenv...

# Installing /usr/sbin/fw_printenv...
--2013-12-30 09:12:27--  http://download.doozan.com/uboot/fw_printenv.md5
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/fw_printenv.md5'

    [ <=>                                   ] 32          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:28 (3.33 MB/s) - `/usr/sbin/fw_printenv.md5' saved [32]

--2013-12-30 09:12:28--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/fw_printenv
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 668497 (653K) []
Saving to: `/usr/sbin/fw_printenv'

100%[======================================>] 668,497     1.46M/s   in 0.4s    

2013-12-30 09:12:28 (1.46 MB/s) - `/usr/sbin/fw_printenv' saved [668497/668497]

# Successfully installed /usr/sbin/fw_printenv.
# checking for /etc/fw_env.config...

# Installing /etc/fw_env.config...
--2013-12-30 09:12:28--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/fw_env.config.md5
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 32 [text/html]
Saving to: `/etc/fw_env.config.md5'

100%[======================================>] 32          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:29 (5.19 MB/s) - `/etc/fw_env.config.md5' saved [32/32]

--2013-12-30 09:12:29--  http:/download.doozan.com/uboot/fw_env.config
Resolving download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to download.doozan.com (download.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 329 []
Saving to: `/etc/fw_env.config'

100%[======================================>] 329         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:30 (45.2 MB/s) - `/etc/fw_env.config' saved [329/329]

# Successfully installed /etc/fw_env.config.

# Validating existing uBoot...
/usr/sbin/nanddump: 1: /usr/sbin/nanddump: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
--2013-12-30 09:12:30--  http:/jeff.doozan.com/uboot/valid-uboot.md5
Resolving jeff.doozan.com (jeff.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to jeff.doozan.com (jeff.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://projects.doozan.com/uboot/valid-uboot.md5 [following]
--2013-12-30 09:12:30--  http:/projects.doozan.com/uboot/valid-uboot.md5
Resolving projects.doozan.com (projects.doozan.com)... 50.116.34.13
Connecting to projects.doozan.com (projects.doozan.com)|50.116.34.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1133 (1.1K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `/tmp/valid-uboot.md5'

100%[======================================>] 1,133       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-12-30 09:12:31 (143 MB/s) - `/tmp/valid-uboot.md5' saved [1133/1133]

md5sum: /tmp/uboot-mtd0-dump: No such file or directory
```

**Did I do irrepairable damage to my OS? It still seems fine for now, but should I fear a reboot?**

Comment: you've run the script.. and now reboot to see what happens.. if it fails _(hope it doesn't)_, maybe then you should look for recovery options..

Comment: *I checked the directory folder on the Ubuntu drive, and sure enough I had written the script to it...* Could you clarify this? *the directory folder*, which directory is that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your concerns. You ran this script on an Ubuntu machine which downloads some files and installs them to `/dev/mtd0`. If you are not running your Ubuntu from a flash card, then that `/dev/mtd0` is an external device, why would this script cause any harm to your Ubuntu system? Your pogoplug device can be damaged, your Ubuntu system not likely.

Also from the output you provided it looks like the script didn't even touch the pogoplug device, just downloaded a bunch of files.